# Add a filter to an openxlsx object with a query activated

Tags: r, add-filter, openxlsx

I'm dumping into a file a report, and I'm using openxlsx to do so, as it can be seen below:

```
library(openxlsx)

set.seed(100)

dataset <- data.frame(A=runif(100),B=runif(100),C=sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace=T))

hs <- createStyle(fontColour = "#ffffff", fgFill = "#4F80BD",
                  halign = "center", valign = "center", textDecoration = "bold",
                  border = "TopBottomLeftRight")

wb = createWorkbook()

  addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "example", gridLines = T, zoom = 70)
  writeData(
    wb, 
    sheet = "example", 
    x = dataset, 
    withFilter=T,
    borders="all",
    borderStyle="thin",
    headerStyle=hs
  ) 
  # The width of the columns will be automatically adjusted
  setColWidths(wb, sheet = "example", cols=1:ncol(dataset), widths = "auto")

saveWorkbook(wb, "example.xlsx", overwrite=T)
```

I've activated the **withFilter** option, so that the end user will be able to select only subsets of data. However, I'd like to activate one filter so that by default only a subset is shown; e.g. I'd like to show only records where the column C equals to "B".

I've reviewed the documentation of the **openxlsx** package, but I can't find how to do it anywhere.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem. did you find out how to do this by now?

Comment: @JoostKeuskamp, I couldn't fine it anywhere. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this sort of active filtering with VBS, but the excel file must be actively open. This could be run after the example.xlsx file is created as you have in post.

In this snippet, I am using base R to create a file that is my VBS script-to-be. Then `writeLines` to, ahem, write lines to the VBS script. This VBS lines/code will open the `example.xlsx`. In this demo, this file lives here: `H:\\R\\practice\\excel\\example.xlsx`

After setting up some defaults, it applies the autofilter. The `3` indicates that it is the 3rd column and the `\"C\"` is where you would change the value to be filtered to. Thus, filter data to show rows where column 3 is equal to "C".

Then filtered version is saved as new file `example_C.xlsx` to show difference/retain original. Then close the workbook and quit the application.

These lines are written to the `H:/R/practice/excel/active_filter.vbs` script and then connection is closed.

finally use `shell.exe` to run vbs script. This script should quickly run, and you should see the file open briefly, filter, then close. If you don't want this then set `xlApp.Visible = FALSE`

```
fileConn <- file("H:/R/practice/excel/active_filter.vbs")
 writeLines(c("Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSht",
             "Dim filename",
             "filename = \"H:\\R\\practice\\excel\\example.xlsx\"",
             "Set xlApp = CreateObject(\"Excel.Application\")",
             "xlApp.Visible = TRUE",
             "set xlBook = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(filename)",
             "set xlSht = xlApp.Worksheets(1)",
             "xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False",
             "xlBook.ActiveSheet.Range(\"A1\").AutoFilter 3, \"C\"",
             "xlBook.SaveAs \"H:\\R\\practice\\excel\\example_C.xlsx\"",
             "xlBook.Close",
             "xlApp.Quit"),
             fileConn)

close(fileConn)

shell.exec("H:/R/practice/excel/active_filter.vbs")
```

Checking both files:

[image]